# Sharing field as composite key and foreign key in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Consider following mapping code please :

```
public sealed class BankMapping : ClassMap<Bank>
{
    public BankMapping()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.SerialNumber, "SerialBankRef")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.FinancialPeriodId, "FinancialPeriodRef");
        Map(x => x.Code);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.Comment);
        Map(x => x.IsActive);            
        HasMany(x => x.BankBranchs).KeyColumns.Add(new[] { "SerialBankRef", "FinancialPeriodRef" });

    }
}
```

And the `BankBranch` mapping code is :

```
public sealed class BankBranchMapping : ClassMap<BankBranch>
{
    public BankBranchMapping()
    {
       CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.FinancialPeriodId, "FinancialPeriodRef")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.SerialNumber, "SerialNumber");
        Map(x => x.Code);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.Comment);
        Map(x => x.IsActive);
        Map(x => x.Address);
        Map(x => x.Fax);
        Map(x => x.Telephone);
        References(x => x.Bank).Columns(new[] { "SerialBankRef", "FinancialPeriodRef" });
    }
}
```

As you can see the `FinancialPeriodRef` field acts as foreign key and part of composite key in the `BankBranch` mapping and NHibernate builds DB correctly and everything seems to be fine until I try to insert a record in the `BankBranch` table.

The error `System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Invalid index 10 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=10.` which indicates I've mapped a field (`FinancialPeriodRef`) twice as FK and PK appears and I have no idea how to fix the problem.

I need `FinancialPeriodRef` in the `BankBranch` as part of primary key while it's absolutely equal to `FinancialPeriodRef` from `Bank`.

I need this field to establish unique constraint and also benefits of composite key is essential.

Comment: Not sure exactly what could cause your problem but the `BankBranchMapping` class mapping is probably not what you want. Look at how the `KeyReference` method is used in this [SO question & accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997114/how-to-map-composite-id-with-fluent-nhibernate-using-an-interface). Using `KeyReference` you can remove the `References(...` from the map. Also, make sure the dependent classes (e.g. `Bank`, etc) have their Id generation set correctly.

Comment: I used the [KeyReference] instead of Reference but the problem still is not solved. The main cause of the error is that NHibernate can not understand why you want to map a DB field two times. Once as ForeignKey and again as Primarykey.

Comment: I am also having this exact problem - did you manage to find a solution? Thanks in advance :]

Answer (score 5):

You need to use KeyReference rather than KeyProperty to describe composite foreign keys.

```
public BankBranchMapping()
{
    CompositeId()
        .KeyReference(x => x.FinancialPeriodId, "FinancialPeriodRef")
        .KeyReference(x => x.SerialNumber, "SerialNumber");
    ...
}
```

I had the exact same problem as you and after an hour or so came across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7997225/569662 which pointed me right.